# Error occurred (InvalidParameterValue)when calling the DescribeDBSnapshots operation:The input isn't valid.Inputcan't contain control characters

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

After long time I am writing the Python scripts to get the RDS snapshot details based on the snapshot names from a file using "for" loop but I am encountering the below error

**botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeDBSnapshots operation: The input isn't valid. Input can't contain control characters.**

Here is the below code that I wrote

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rds',region_name='us-west-2')
file   = open('/rds_snapshot_delete_sample.txt','r')
for k in file:
  response = client.describe_db_snapshots(DBSnapshotIdentifier=k)
  print(response)
```

And I am running it like below

```
python3 filename.py
```

the file "rds_snapshot_delete_sample.txt" contains the rds snapshot names like below

"abcdefgh"

Can any one please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your data likely has control characters that are being fed into the boto3 call.  Here's how you might correct it:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rds', region_name='us-west-2')

with open('/rds_snapshot_delete_sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        response = client.describe_db_snapshots(DBSnapshotIdentifier=line.strip())
        print(response)
```

You should consider using an IDE like PyCharm that would allow you to put a breakpoint at the describe call and see the input while you're running the code.  It will help you discover these kinds of issues in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Coin Graham, your input helped me to solve my issue.